# Using Stack to check balance for multiple lines of code

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to write code that checks balance for {}, () and [] in any file(with multiple lines). If the file is not balanced report the place(line and character number) where the error occured 
Here's my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Stack;
public class CppJavaParser {
    public static class Symbol{
        public char symbol;
        public int lineFound;
        public int colFound;

        public Symbol( char symb, int line, int charIndex){
            symbol = symb;
            lineFound = line;
            colFound = charIndex;
        }
    }

    public static Stack<Symbol> symbolStack = new Stack<Symbol>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("HelloWorld.java"))));
        String line;
        int lineNum = 1;
        while( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
            balanceChecker(line, lineNum);
            lineNum++;
        }
        br.close();
        if (symbolStack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Failure");
        }
    }

    public static void balanceChecker(String line, int lineNum){
        int charNum = 1;
        Symbol top;
        for(char chr : line.toCharArray()){
            switch(chr) {
            case '{':
            case '(':
            case '[':
                symbolStack.push(new Symbol(chr, lineNum, charNum));
                break;

            case ']':
                if (symbolStack.isEmpty())
                    System.err.println("Unmatched parentheses ");
                else
                {
                    top = symbolStack.peek();
                    if (top.symbol != '[') {
                        System.err.println("Fail at line: " + top.lineFound
                                + " Column: " + top.colFound);
                    }else{
                        symbolStack.pop();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case ')':
                if (symbolStack.isEmpty())
                    System.err.println("Unmatched parentheses ");
                else {
                    top = symbolStack.peek();
                    if (top.symbol != '(') {
                        System.err.println("Fail at line: " + top.lineFound
                                + " Column: " + top.colFound);
                    }else{
                        symbolStack.pop();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case '}':
                if (symbolStack.isEmpty())
                    System.err.println("Unmatched parentheses ");
                else {
                    top = symbolStack.peek();
                    if ((top.symbol != '{')) {
                        System.err.println("Fail at line: " + top.lineFound
                                + " Column: " + top.colFound);
                    }else{
                        symbolStack.pop();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            charNum++;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the test file I am using:

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
}//This is where unmatched parenthesis error occurs
```

My program prints following to the console:

```
Unmatched parentheses 
Success
```

How come it prints Success? it should not print that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("HelloWorld.java")))); // Reading
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // test
                                                                                // file
        String line;
        int lineNum = 1;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            balanceChecker(line, lineNum);
            lineNum++;
        }
        br.close();
        if (symbolStack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Failure");
        }
    }

    public static void balanceChecker(String line, int lineNum) {
        int charNum = 1;
        Symbol top;
        for (char chr : line.toCharArray()) {
            switch (chr) {
            case '{':
            case '(':
            case '[':
                symbolStack.push(new Symbol(chr, lineNum, charNum));
                break;

            case ']':
                if (symbolStack.isEmpty())
                    System.err.println("Unmatched parentheses ");
                else
                {
                    top = symbolStack.pop();
                    if (top.symbol != '[') {
                        System.err.println("Fail at line: " + top.lineFound
                                + " Column: " + top.colFound);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case ')':
                if (symbolStack.isEmpty())
                    System.err.println("Unmatched parentheses ");
                else {
                    top = symbolStack.pop();

                    if (top.symbol != '(') {
                        System.err.println("Fail at line: " + top.lineFound
                                + " Column: " + top.colFound);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case '}':
                if (symbolStack.isEmpty())
                    System.err.println("Unmatched parentheses ");
                else {
                    top = symbolStack.pop();

                    if ((top.symbol != '{')) {
                        System.err.println("Fail at line: " + top.lineFound
                                + " Column: " + top.colFound);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            charNum++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For unmatched closing parentheses ? E.g. `()))`

Comment: I think checking if the stack is empty is important because if the stack is empty and you find an ending symbol (i.e. '}',')' or ']') that would mean that there is an extra unwanted ending symbol. And it needs to be reported.

Comment: @ranifisch Well, now you got the error explanation, but you are late with solution =).

Comment: The edited answer works wonderfully for reporting errors. However it prints "Success" after reporting the error. For Example, Fail at line: 4 Column: 27
Success

Comment: You can add a boolean to know if there was failure and not print the Success output

Comment: I solved it by using errorCounter. If errorCounter > 0 {failure}

Answer (score 2):

check your code line:
 if( (symbolStack.isEmpty()) || (top.symbol != '[') ){ ===> print failure

so you check if the stack is empty (after the pop) , if there was one proper symbol entry on the stack that matches your close tag, the stack is emty and it will print  failure

You should check for an empty stack before popping and then if empty print an error, if not pop and check the symbol....

Comment: This is a subtle, yet important distinction from the other answers.  You can't remove the check entirely, but the order in which the operations are performed is causing the error.